# Why am I getting a "cannot open file" error with gfortran in MacOS Ventura?

Tags: macos, gfortran

I just updated to MacOS Ventura. No matter what Fortran code I try to compile, using something standard like:

`gfortran my_code.f90 -o my_code.x`

I get the error `Fatal Error: cannot open input file`

How do I resolve this? According to Software Update, everything is up-to-date.

Comment: `ls -l my_code.f90` - are you sure you have correct file permissions and are in the right working directory? Edit: Oh wait - Ventura. Make sure terminal (and maybe gfortran itself?) have full disk access permissions or whatever it is that needs to get set up for programs to read files on disk.

Answer (score 0):

Ventura adds a lot more layers of access restrictions. Make sure the programs you need to use have "Full Disk Access" set if necessary:

[image]

Comment: +1 for this, which I did not know about. Unfortunately, the problem (of not being able to compile) persists. I get a new error. I'll edit my question accordingly.

Comment: Compile with a `-v` flag and show the whole command line and output, please.